# How to create subfolders while using FOR /F in a Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I want to process a folder and files in sub folders and after processing want to move files to new location (folder).

Current command is working **but it is not creating sub folders and generating all new files in same folder** (i.e. output folder)

```
for /F %%i in (filelist.txt) do (process.exe %%i > output\%%~nxi)
```

I need it to save it in same folder structure, as its source folder.

Where filelist.txt (source folder) is:

```
c:\backup\oldwork\browse.asp
c:\backup\oldwork\capital.asp
c:\backup\oldwork\make.asp
c:\backup\oldwork\conf\config.asp
c:\backup\oldwork\conf\global.asp
```

and I want my script to generate output (destination folder) like:

```
c:\backup\output\browse.asp
c:\backup\output\capital.asp
c:\backup\output\make.asp
c:\backup\output\conf\config.asp
c:\backup\output\conf\global.asp
```

Currently above For /F command is generating output like:

```
c:\backup\output\browse.asp
c:\backup\output\capital.asp
c:\backup\output\make.asp
**c:\backup\output\config.asp** (not following directory structure)
**c:\backup\output\global.asp**
```

Comment: What is your question?  There's not even question mark in your question lol.

Comment: Basically I want to process existing files, like append some text in each file and move it to some new location, files in sub folders moved to new location sub folder, currently files are moving to output folder (with above FOR /f command) but without directory structure. I have to manually find and re-create sub folders

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't work is to do with what your outputting:

```
output\%%~nxi
```

Where if you check your documentation you would see:

```
You can now use the following optional syntax:

    %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
    %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
    %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
    %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
    %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
    %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
    %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
    %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
    %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
    %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
                   environment variable and expands %I to the
                   fully qualified name of the first one found.
                   If the environment variable name is not
                   defined or the file is not found by the
                   search, then this modifier expands to the
                   empty string

The modifiers can be combined to get compound results:

    %~nxI       - expands %I to a file name and extension only
```

Since you are only expanding to name and extension, the folder structure is ignored.

#### Solution:

What I would do in your situation is this, change your `filelist.txt` to this format:

```
browse.asp
capital.asp
make.asp
conf\config.asp
conf\global.asp
```

And then change your for-loop as such:

```
for /F %%i in (filelist.txt) do (process.exe c:\backup\oldwork\%%i > output\%%i)
```

Which should work out for you.

Comment: and how to make filelist.txt like this? 
Currently I am using :

`dir %cd%\*.asp  /A:-D /B /O:N /S >> %cd%\filelist.txt`

Answer (score 0):

```
for /F %%i in (filelist.txt) do (md "output%%~pi"&process.exe %%i > "output%%~pnxi")
```

should do the task, creating `output\backup\oldwork\browse.asp` etc. (for lack of adequate description of required result)

Comment: first of all thanks for your help, Your command is working but it is just omitting drive letter and creating
`output\backup\oldwork\files`

Like @Monacraft said, I have to remove full path from filelist.txt while making file list, but not sure how???? currently I am using

`dir %cd%\*.asp /A:-D /B /O:N /S >> %cd%\filelist.txt`

Comment: If you want the same drive as is in your source textfile, simply prefix the `output%%~p` with `%%~di` thus: `"%%~di""output%%~p` - you still have not explicitly stated what your desired output format is. If that solution doesn't work, plase edit your original post to show what the actual original filenames and result filenames are. I believe @Monacraft solution hasn't taken into account that the sourcefile **must** include the source directoryname since it is used as a parameter to `process.exe`

Comment: Source and destination file names and directory names sub folders will be same, it just process and put copy of source files in new folder "output"

Comment: I updated my question, also when I tried `for /F %%i in (filelist.txt) do (md "%%~di""output%%~p"&process.exe %%i > "output%%~pnxi")` It is still not working and giving error `A subdirectory or file c:output%~p already exists.`